# Monodromy Representation of Elliptic Curve

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, homotopy-theory, elliptic-curves, covering-spaces

I'm reading [this post](https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2010/02/25/monodromy-representations/)  by Charles Siegel on Monodromy Representations
and there is a construction in example a not unterstand.

We look at the family $y^2z=x(x-z)(x-\lambda z)$ of projective elliptic
curves parametrized by $\lambda$.
We’re ignoring degenerations for the moment so this lives over
$\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,1,\infty\}$. This is also visible as
$\mathbb{C}^\times\setminus\{1\}$.

Since topologically this space
is homotopy equivalent to two-loop space $S^1 \vee S^1$, we have
$\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\times\setminus\{1\})= \mathbb{Z}  * \mathbb{Z}$
we’ve got two nontrivial loops,
one around zero, the other around one, and there are no relations,
this is the free group of rank $2$:

[image]

We can envision all of this as
living in the plane with four points marked as ${0,1,\infty,\lambda}$,
and a cut from ${0}$ to ${\lambda}$ and a cut from ${1}$ to ${\infty}$.
Then the loops are what happens if we loop ${\lambda}$ around things.
We get one loop from rotating the cut between ${0}$ and ${\lambda}$
all the way around. The other one is a bit trickier to describe
directly, but we can describe it in terms like this.

Later we consider the action of the two loops from
$\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \{0,1,\infty\})$ on the homology
group $H_1$ of the elliptic curve. The generators of $H_1$ are:

[image]

We’ll focus on the first one. Look at ${H_1}$ of the elliptic curve.
It has two generators, call them ${\delta}$ and ${\gamma}$, where
${\delta}$ is a loop around the ${0\lambda}$ cut, and ${\gamma}$ is a
loop through the two cuts. This is a standard homology basis,
and we’ll look at the action of our element of
$\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,1,\infty\})$ on the homology:

There are some aspects I not understand in this construction. Firstly, what
does the author mean when he wrote 'The loops are what happens if we
loop $\lambda$ around things. We get one loop from rotating
the cut between ${0}$ and ${\lambda}$ all the way around.' Which
loops do we obtain by this operation rotating the cut between
${0}$ and ${\lambda}$? I not understand which objects we obtain doing
it. The only involved loops here are the two generators of
$\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,1,\infty\})$ called
$\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ and the two generators of $H_1$ of the
elliptic curve $\delta$ and $\gamma$ in second picture, which
as far as I understand the second picture represents one
"sheet" of the elliptic curve. I would like do understand which loops the author has in mind?

Is the which the author has in 'We get one loop from rotating the cut between
$0$ and $λ$ all the way around' just literally this one:

[image]

Secondly why the induced action by
$\gamma_2 \in \pi_1(\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{0,1,\infty\})$ on $H_1$
correspond precisely to the rotations of the cut between ${0}$ and
${\lambda}$ discussed in first part? Can somebody explain the geometry of this action?

Comment: For a loop $C\in  \pi^1(\Bbb{C}^*-1; \lambda_0) $, it would be natural to consider the unique function $f_C\to [0,1]\times E_{\lambda_0}\to E_{C(t)}\subset \Bbb{P^2(C)}$ such that $f_C(0,.)=Id$ and $f_C$ is continuous and $f_C(t,.)$ is a group isomorphism $E_{\lambda_0}\to E_{C(t)}$. Then $f_C(1,.)$ is an automorphism of $E_{\lambda_0}$ (so it must be either $Id$ or $[-1]$) and we'd like to know which homotopy classes $C$ give the trivial automorphism.

Comment: Ok, I see that the map $f_C$ is uniquely determined by loop
$C\in  \pi^1(\Bbb{C}^*-1; \lambda_0)$ using basic lifting theorems and
and the fact that $Aut(E_{\lambda_0})=\{\pm 1\}$.  
So the loop which the author is talking about in the sentences
'Then the loops are what happens if we loop λ around things'. 
We get one loop from rotating the cut between 
$0$ and $λ$ all the way around' is simply the guy in the 
third pucture I attatched to the updated question just now, 
nothing more, right?